# printing json array containing svg elements in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, svg

I've been having some difficulties getting a json string constructed in javascript and posted to a php page to print properly. I used a form to post the data and access it using:

```
$json = $_POST['printMatter'];
```

The json string looks like this:

```
[{"type":"page","value":"page3"},{"type":"row","value":"newrow13"},{"type":"rowTitle","value":"Demographics"},{"type":"chartTitle","value":"Percentage of respondents by sex"},{"type":"chartSVG","value":"<g transform="translate(168.33333333333334,75)" class="arc"><path style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);" toggle="off" d="M2.4492935982947065e-15,-40A40,40 0 1,1 -26.947825745862282,-29.560356688826367L-11.228260727442619,-12.316815287010987A16.666666666666668,16.666666666666668 0 1,0 1.0205389992894611e-15,-16.666666666666668Z"></path><title style="text-anchor: middle;" dy=".35em" transform="translate(10.235180541969331,26.420046499790082)">1 (N:15; 88.2%)</title></g><g transform="translate(168.33333333333334,75)" class="arc"><path style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);" toggle="off" d="M-26.947825745862282,-29.560356688826367A40,40 0 0,1 -7.347880794884118e-15,-40L-3.061616997868383e-15,-16.666666666666668A16.666666666666668,16.666666666666668 0 0,0 -11.228260727442619,-12.316815287010987Z"></path><title style="text-anchor: middle;" dy=".35em" transform="translate(-10.235180541969335,-26.420046499790082)">2 (N:2; 11.8%)</title></g><rect style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);" height="15" y="58" width="15" x="326.6666666666667" class="arc"></rect><rect style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);" height="15" y="75" width="15" x="326.6666666666667" class="arc"></rect><text style="font-size: 12px;" y="71" x="346.6666666666667">1</text><text style="font-size: 12px;" y="88" x="346.6666666666667">2</text>"},{"type":"chartTitle","value":"Percentage of respondents by age"},{"type":"chartSVG","value":"<g transform="translate(168.33333333333334,75)" class="arc"><path style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);" toggle="off" d="M0,40A40,40 0 1,1 0,-40A40,40 0 1,1 0,40M0,16.666666666666668A16.666666666666668,16.666666666666668 0 1,0 0,-16.666666666666668A16.666666666666668,16.666666666666668 0 1,0 0,16.666666666666668Z"></path><title style="text-anchor: middle;" dy=".35em" transform="translate(1.7349162987920838e-15,28.333333333333336)">2 (N:17; 100.0%)</title></g><rect style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);" height="15" y="66.5" width="15" x="326.6666666666667" class="arc"></rect><text style="font-size: 12px;" y="79.5" x="346.6666666666667">2</text>"},{"type":"chartTitle","value":"Percentage of respondents by education"},{"type":"chartSVG","value":"<g transform="translate(168.33333333333334,75)" class="arc"><path style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);" toggle="off" d="M2.4492935982947065e-15,-40A40,40 0 1,1 -21.057286515094237,34.00868542918457L-8.773869381289266,14.170285595493569A16.666666666666668,16.666666666666668 0 1,0 1.0205389992894611e-15,-16.666666666666668Z"></path><title style="text-anchor: middle;" dy=".35em" transform="translate(27.25172655656321,7.753784718709017)">2 (N:10; 58.8%)</title></g><g transform="translate(168.33333333333334,75)" class="arc"><path style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);" toggle="off" d="M-21.057286515094237,34.00868542918457A40,40 0 0,1 -39.82936705180138,-3.6907343785320994L-16.59556960491724,-1.5378059910550417A16.666666666666668,16.666666666666668 0 0,0 -8.773869381289266,14.170285595493569Z"></path><title style="text-anchor: middle;" dy=".35em" transform="translate(-25.362959921726773,12.629253413668577)">3 (N:3; 17.6%)</title></g><g transform="translate(168.33333333333334,75)" class="arc"><path style="fill: rgb(44, 160, 44);" toggle="off" d="M-39.82936705180138,-3.6907343785320994A40,40 0 0,1 -26.947825745862282,-29.560356688826367L-11.228260727442619,-12.316815287010987A16.666666666666668,16.666666666666668 0 0,0 -16.59556960491724,-1.5378059910550417Z"></path><title style="text-anchor: middle;" dy=".35em" transform="translate(-25.362959921726766,-12.629253413668595)">1 (N:2; 11.8%)</title></g><g transform="translate(168.33333333333334,75)" class="arc"><path style="fill: rgb(214, 39, 40);" toggle="off" d="M-26.947825745862282,-29.560356688826367A40,40 0 0,1 -14.449666647486119,-37.298889176174235L-6.02069443645255,-15.541203823405931A16.666666666666668,16.666666666666668 0 0,0 -11.228260727442619,-12.316815287010987Z"></path><title style="text-anchor: middle;" dy=".35em" transform="translate(-14.915577948191759,-24.089485512339063)">5 (N:1; 5.9%)</title></g><g transform="translate(168.33333333333334,75)" class="arc"><path style="fill: rgb(148, 103, 189);" toggle="off" d="M-14.449666647486119,-37.298889176174235A40,40 0 0,1 -7.347880794884118e-15,-40L-3.061616997868383e-15,-16.666666666666668A16.666666666666668,16.666666666666668 0 0,0 -6.02069443645255,-15.541203823405931Z"></path><title style="text-anchor: middle;" dy=".35em" transform="translate(-5.20623633813615,-27.850904491043888)">6 (N:1; 5.9%)</title></g><rect style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);" height="15" y="32.5" width="15" x="326.6666666666667" class="arc"></rect><rect style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);" height="15" y="49.5" width="15" x="326.6666666666667" class="arc"></rect><rect style="fill: rgb(44, 160, 44);" height="15" y="66.5" width="15" x="326.6666666666667" class="arc"></rect><rect style="fill: rgb(214, 39, 40);" height="15" y="83.5" width="15" x="326.6666666666667" class="arc"></rect><rect style="fill: rgb(148, 103, 189);" height="15" y="100.5" width="15" x="326.6666666666667" class="arc"></rect><text style="font-size: 12px;" y="45.5" x="346.6666666666667">2</text><text style="font-size: 12px;" y="62.5" x="346.6666666666667">3</text><text style="font-size: 12px;" y="79.5" x="346.6666666666667">1</text><text style="font-size: 12px;" y="96.5" x="346.6666666666667">5</text><text style="font-size: 12px;" y="113.5" x="346.6666666666667">6</text>"},{"type":"row","value":"newrow23"}]
```

I'm able to see this by creating some javascript from within the php file as such:

```
$blurb = "<script> 
  alert('" . $json . "'); 
</script>";
echo $blurb;
```

However, when I try to simply echo $json as follows:

```
echo $json;
```

The result is that I get bits of $json showing up on the page but other bits - mainly the SVG code in the json string ends up as html code that doesn't appear as text (i.e. I can see it in my console/inspector).

When I try to use `echo json_decode($json)` I just get 'Array'

If I then do:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r(json_decode($json));
echo "</pre>";
```

Then I get something that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [type] => page
        [value] => page3
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [type] => row
        [value] => newrow13
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [type] => rowTitle
        [value] => Demographics
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [type] => chartTitle
        [value] => Percentage of respondents by sex
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [type] => chartSVG
        [value] => 12
    )
```

...

As you can see the last entry above, [4], of type 'chartSVG' shows a value of 12 whereas it should contain a long svg string.

I also can't seem to access different elements in the Array - e.g. by doing `echo $json[2]`

I feel I must be missing something obvious but my searching hasn't yielded anything. Any advice/guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in that you send invalid JSON from JavaScript. You can copy-paste your JSON to something like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to see that there is error in your SVG

```
Parse error on line 20:
...ue": "<g transform="translate(168.333333
-----------------------^
Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'
```

as you send HTML within it and it contains ".

So when you are building your JSON on client, make sure you use *\"* instead of plain *"* in strings included in JSON. In JS this can be done with something like

```
var val = input.replace('"', '\"');
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The string on the client side includes \ for all the " within html (I use JSON.stringify on an object to get the string). When it goes across to the php page and I use the `print_r` command as explained above, this all seems to disappear. I tested the client side json in JSONLint and it says it's valid json. Could you please explain why this is happening and what I can do about it? Thank you